# Avoiding a loop in matrix index

Tags: r

dist is an nxn matrix of costs:

```
dist <-matrix(c(0,3.2,1.2,3.2,0,0.5,1.2,0.5,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)
```

v is a vector of length n, where the index of the vector corresponds to the row of dist, and the value in the vector corresponds to the column of dist

```
v <- c(2,2,3)
```

I want to sum the costs like this:

```
cost <- 0

for(i in 1:length(v)){

    cost <- dist[i,v[i]] + cost

}
```

but this seems clumsy and slow. What is the trick to doing this without the for loop?  Is the for loop not taking advantage of some magical R alternative?  Suggestions please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to `cbind` with the row index to extract the values and `sum`

```
sum(dist[cbind(1:nrow(dist), v)])
```